# Recursively access the last values from array within hash

Tags: ruby

The input may come something from `string` or `array` within `hash`.

However,

- `Hash` could be recursive.
- `Array` could have multiple values.

Example;

```
  # ex.1  "name must be a string"
  # ex.2 {"name"=>["name must be a string"]}
  # ex.3  {"name"=>["name must be a string", "name must be greater than 3"]}
  # ex.4 {"payment"=> {"currency"=>["currency must be a jpy"]}}
  # ex.5 {"payment"=> {"currency"=>["currency must be a jpy", "currency must be string"]}}
```

I'd love to render the string or each of the last values within array.

```
  # ex.1 method(x) => "name must be a string"
  # ex.2 method(x) => "name must be a string"
  # ex.3 method(x) => "name must be a string"/ "name must be greater than 3"
  # ex.4 method(x) => "currency must be a jpy"
  # ex.5 method(x) => "currency must be a jpy"/ "currency must be string"
```

Comment: What would be the return value for `{ 1=>{2=>[3,4], 3=>[5,6] }`? For `{ 1=>{ 2=>[[4,5], { 6=>7 }] } }`?

Comment: It should return [3,4,5,6].

Comment: I have created the tiny library for deep iterating arrays and hashes https://github.com/am-kantox/iteraptor — you might want to check it’s code for inspiration.

Comment: That my first example should return `[3,4,5,6]` is not evident from the statement of the question. You therefore should clarify the question with an edit, rather than elaborating in comments. (For one, not all readers read all comments.) Please also address my second example in your edit. More generally, when writing (or editing) a question, try to think of examples for which your statement of the problem is incomplete or ambiguous. One more thing: rarely can you write a clear and complete question with examples alone. First use words, then give one or more examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def leaves(input, acc = [])
  if input.is_a?(Enumerable)
    input.each_with_object(acc) { |e, acc| leaves([*e].last, acc) }
  else
    acc << input
  end
end 

leaves({ 1=>{2=>[3,4], 3=>[5,[6, 7]] }})
#⇒ [3, 4, 5, 7]
```

Comment: OMG. This is the one! Thank you! I wanted to use recursive method like this. By the way what is [*e]? I'm new to ruby..

Comment: For arrays, `e` would be be a single elem, for hashes, `e` would be an array of two elements: key and value. I produce the array out of anything and get it’s last elem, to avoid nested conditionals. In pseudocode it would be `[e OR [k, v]].flatten.last ⇒ e OR v`.

Comment: I might have misunderstood the question. I'm not sure 5 should be here, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
def last_values(val)
  vals = if val.is_a?(Hash)
           val = val[val.keys.last]
           return val.values.flatten if val.is_a?(Hash) # for Hash fetch the last one
           return val.flatten # for Array
         else
           [val]
         end

  vals.each do |each|
     p each
  end
end
```

This could work.
However if you have any other good solutions, please post it up :)